# database connection problem

Tags: php

i am just a beginner and simply trying to read data from a db.there are 2 files, one is include file which contains db connection code and another the 2nd part of my given below code.In db, 3 columns there: 1.id, 2.name and 3. description when i try to open the located folder in firefox it shows

> "Fatal error: Call to undefined
>   function mysql_fetch_arrey() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\www\database
>   connection\index.php on line 8"

the 8 num line is

> "while($person =
>   mysql_fetch_arrey($result))"

i am checked the "mysql_fetch_arrey($result)" with "$mysql_fetch_arrey($result)"

but it shows

> "Fatal error: Function name must be a
>   string in C:\xampp\htdocs\www\database
>   connection\index.php on line 8"

i use adobe dreamwaver5 and xampp server

1st page :

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>connection</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php

    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';
    $db = 'db_connection';

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
    mysql_select_db($db);

    ?>



</body>
</html>

</body>
</html>
```

2nd page :

```
<?php

include 'connection.php';

$query = "SELECT * FROM people";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($person = $mysql_fetch_arrey($result))
    {
        echo "<h3>".$person['name']."</h3>";
        echo "<p>".$person['description']."</p>";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function's name is [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), not mysql_fetch_arrey. So your while loop should like:

```
while($person = $mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: ohh!!...how silly i am...:P....yes, u right. It was a spelling mistake. i must improve my observation capability and thanks a lot dear, for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Typo here `$mysql_fetch_arrey`

This should be

```
while($person = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```